# 100% width in three-column layers?

Tags: html, css

Having this html:

```
<div class="images_portfolio panel-widget-style">
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<a href="imagelink"><img src="x.jpg" alt="" /></a>
</div>
```

and this css:

```
.images_portfolio.panel-widget-style a img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}

.images_portfolio.panel-widget-style a {
    position:relative;
    display:block;width:32%;margin-right:1%;
    float:left;
    margin-bottom:1%;
}
```

it

I can get 32%+32%+32% = 96%  + margin right (1%*3) = 99% in total of parent element.

How can i get 100% of parent element so it works in all major browsers? Number of links can vary so I never know if it's 5 or 18 etc... (I want the the images to be aligned to an element down below that is 100%. Hope you understand what I mean).

Comment: Try using `width: 33,33333333%` and instead of `margin-right` use `padding-right`. Padding is offset inside the element that counts towards elements width.

Comment: Is that valid in all major browsers? I do want some space between the images as well. Therefore using margin-right

Comment: Even though it's not yet fully supported by all browsers, you should read about flexbox and let it handle the problem for you. For support see http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @Martin - thanks a lot! Make that an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: use calc() method of css;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `width: 33,33333333%` and instead of `margin-right` use `padding-right`. Padding is offset inside the element that counts towards elements width.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Simple but effetctive. The trick was to use padding instead of margin.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with javascript for example

https://jsfiddle.net/fx1azr4q/

```
    (function() {
      var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
      [].forEach.call(elements, function (el) {
        el.style.width = (100-elements.length)/elements.length + '%';
      });
    })();
```

Comment: This seems like a waste of resources? I want to do this in pure css.

Comment: And you offer flexbox with minimum 10 knows issues and special page with workarounds?